# Nancy Empty Self Hosting - System.AccessViolationException

Tags: nancy, sidewaffle

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition in Administrator mode. I installed **SideWaffle Template Pack v1.21.400**. I created a new **Nancy Empty Self Host Project**. The below is the Source Code:

```
using System;
using Nancy.Hosting.Self;

namespace NancyEmptySelfHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var uri =
                new Uri("http://localhost:3579");

            using (var host = new NancyHost(uri))
            {
                host.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Your application is running on " + uri);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any [Enter] to close the host.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On execution, I am getting **System.AccessViolationException** in the line `host.Start();` with the below message:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

I get the same exception, when I create Projects with other Nancy Templates. If I create a Console application (without using Nancy template) and refer Nancy dlls, it's working fine. How should this be fixed?